# Time evolution of a Bayesian posterior

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, posterior

I have a question regarding the time evolution of a quantity related to a Bayesian posterior.

Suppose we have binary parameter space $\{ s_1, s_2 \}$ with prior $(p, 1-p)$,
The data generating processes are Brownian motions with parameter-determined drift:

$$
dX_t = \theta_i(t) dt + dB_t
$$

for deterministic functions $\theta_i(t)$, $i = 1, 2$.

By Girsanov's theorem, the likelihood ratio, conditional on $X_t$, as a stochastic process is $e^{\gamma_t}$

where

$$
\gamma_t = \int_0^t \theta_1(s) - \theta_2(s) dB_s - \int_0^t \frac{ \theta_1^2(s) - \theta_2^2(s) }{2} ds. 
$$

So the posterior probability (of $s_1$) is then given by

$$
\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) }.
$$

**Question**: Can one describe explicitly how $E[\frac{e^{\gamma_t} p}{ (e^{\gamma_t} p + (1 - p))^2 }]$ evolves?

Direct calculation, by Ito's lemma, shows that

$$
d \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) }
= (1 - p) \frac{1}{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2} d pe^{\gamma_t} - 
  (1 - p) \frac{1}{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^{3}} ( d pe^{\gamma_t} )^2 \\
$$

So

\begin{align*}
\frac{ d E[ \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) }] }{dt} &=
(1 - p) E[\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}] (\theta_1^2(t) - \theta_2^2(t))  \\ 
&\; - (1 - p) E[\frac{( p e^{\gamma_t})^2 }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^3}] \ (\theta_1^2(t) - \theta_2^2(t)) , 
\end{align*}

i.e.

\begin{align*}
\frac{ d E[ \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) }]}{dt} &=
(1 - p) 
E[\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}(1- \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) })] \cdot (\theta_1^2(t) - \theta_2^2(t)) \\
&= (1 - p) [\;
E[\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}] E[1- \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) }]\\
&\; + Cov(\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}, 1- \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p }) \;]  \cdot (\theta_1^2(t) - \theta_2^2(t)) \\
&= 0. \\
\end{align*}

The last inequality follows from the fact that successive Bayesian priors form a martingale: let $p(s)$ be the prior, $q(s)$ be the posterior, and
$p(x|s)$ be the conditional densities, then

\begin{align*}
E[q(s)] &= E[ \frac{ p(x|s)p(s) }{ \int  p(x|s')p(s') ds' }] \\
        &= \int \frac{ p(x|s)p(s) }{ \int  p(x|s')p(s') ds' } 
          \int p(x|s')p(s') ds' dx\\
        &= \int p(x|s) p(s) dx \\
        &= p(s).
\end{align*}

So the whole thing boils down to

\begin{align*}
0 &= E[\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}(1- \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) })] \\
&= E[\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}] E[1- \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) }]\\
&\; + Cov(\frac{p e^{\gamma_t} }{(p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}, 1- \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p }).
\end{align*}

The question is then whether one can solve for $E[ \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ ( p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}]$ from above---by computing the time evolution of the covariance term. Or, is there another way to get at this?

**Follow Up Question**:
Does $\frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ ( p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) )^2}$ have a Bayesian interpretation? Why should it be orthogonal to $1- \frac{ p e^{\gamma_t} }{ p e^{\gamma_t} + (1 - p) }$---the posterior probability of
the other state $s_2$---at all times $t$?

Comment: How are the parameters $s_1$ and $s_2$ involved in the data generating process?